# Why does socket become disconnected?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.8

I am trying to create a chat server between 2 machines but there's a problem with the connection. Although it initially connects, when it comes to sending any actual data the socket becomes disconnected.

**Server code**

```
import socket
import sys
import time
messages = []

x= socket.socket()
h_name = socket.gethostname()
print('Server will start on host address:', h_name)
port = 8000

bind = False
while bind == False:
   try:
      x.bind((h_name, port))
      bind = True
      print('This server is running on port', port)
   except(OSError): #if the port connection doesn't work
      if port == 65535:
         print('Please restart the machine and relaunch this program')
      else:
         port = port + 1 #increment the port by 1 and try again
         print('Trying Port ' + str(port) + '...')

print( "Server done binding to host and port successfully")
print("Server is waiting for incoming connections")
x.listen(1)
connection,address= x.accept()
print(address, "has connected to the server and is now online...")

while 1:
   display_mess= input(str(">>"))
   if display_mess == 'QUIT': #if the user wants to quit
      confirmation = input('Are you sure you would like to quit (Y/N)? ')
      confirmation = confirmation.upper()
      if confirmation == 'Y':
         print('Press enter to quit...')
         input()
         exit()
   else:
   display_mess=display_mess.encode()
   connection.send(display_mess)
   print("Message has been sent...")
   in_message=connection.recv(1024)
   in_message=in_message.decode()
   print("Client:", in_message)
```

The above code should set up a server and wait for a connection from the client and then they should be able to communicate, albeit one single message at a time. The server should send the message first and then the client.

**Client code**

```
import socket
import sys
import time
global port
port = 8000


def getHostName():
   global h_name
   h_name= input(str("Enter the hostname of the server: "))

def portConnect(h_name,port):
   x = socket.socket()
   connected = False
   while connected == False:
      x = socket.socket()
      try:
         x.connect((h_name,port))
         print("Connected to chat server")
         connected = True
      except(ConnectionRefusedError):
         print('Port', port, 'is incorrect')
         print('Trying port ' + str(port+1) + '...')
         port = int(port+1)
         portConnect(h_name,port)

def while1():
   x = socket.socket()
   while 1:
      x = socket.socket()
      try:
         incoming_message=x.recv(1024)
         incoming_message=incoming_message.decode()
         print(" Server :", incoming_message)
         message= input(str(">>"))
         if message == 'QUIT':
            confirmation = input('Are you sure you would like to quit (Y/N)? ')
            confirmation = confirmation.upper()
            if confirmation == 'Y':
               print('Press enter to quit...')
               input()
               exit()
            else:
               message =message.encode()
               x.send(message)
               print(" message has been sent...")
         else:
            message =message.encode()
            x.send(message)
            print(" message has been sent...")

      except(OSError):
         print('Please check the server machine is running')
         cont = input('Would you like to quit the program or continue (Q/C): ')
         if cont.isnum() != True and len(cont) > 0:
            cont = cont.upper()
            if cont == 'C':
               getHostName()
            else:
               print('Press enter to exit')
               input()
               exit()

getHostName()
portConnect(h_name, port)
while1()
```

The above code should create a client machine and search for the server on the predetermined port and LAN and wait for a connection from the server and then they should be able to communicate, albeit one single message at a time. The server should send the message first and then the client.

**Console output (on client's machine')**

```
Enter the hostname of the server: *name*
Connected to chat server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "******.py", line 71, in <module>
    while1()
  File "******.py", line 38, in while1
    incoming_message=x.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

The console output says they do initially connect as it displays the `Connected to chat server` message but then they disconnect as the server cannot send any message.

If the server tries to send a message after the socket has been disconnected, the console output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "******.py", line 43, in <module>
      in_message=connection.recv(1024)
  ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I imagine, however, this issue will solve itself after the socket problem has been sorted.

Comment: You should attempt to create a minimal example that still has the issue that you are experiencing.  I suspect that the issue is that you are recreating the socket in each function instead of passing around the connected socket.

Answer (score 2):

The big hint as to what's wrong is looking at how many times you call `socket.socket` in the client code. I see four different places where you create a **new** socket: twice in `while1`, and twice in `portConnect`. That's surely not what you want. Your code is failing because you connect the socket created in `portConnect`, then that socket object goes out of scope when the function exits. The `x` in `portConnect` is not the same `x` in `while1`.

I'd pass `x` in to `portConnect` instead of using the newly created socket:

```
def portConnect(h_name, port, x):
    # Don't create a new socket here
    connected = False
    while connected == False:
        # Also don't create a new socket here
    . . .
```

Then move the call to `portConnect` to somewhere where `x` is in scope, and call it as:

```
portConnect(h_name, port, x)
```

You also probably want to get rid of the `x = socket.socket()` inside of the `while 1:` loop.

You could also create `x` in `portConnect`, and then `return` it from the function. You may find that that makes more sense.

---

A few side things:

- `while1` is a very poor name for a function. The name should describe what the function does, not details about its implementation.
- `while 1` is more clear as `while True`.
- Conditions like `while connected == False:` are more readable and idiomatic as `while not connected:`. Comparing against `True` and `False` directly is never necessary.

Comment: The message now sends but when trying a new power at start up this happens:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/***", line 20, in portConnect
    x.connect((h_name,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ***", line 68, in <module>
    portConnect(h_name, port,x)
  ***.py", line 27, in portConnect
    portConnect(h_name,port,x)
  ***", line 20, in portConnect
    x.connect((h_name,port))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: @user14303139 Double check what `h_name` and `port` are. What `h_name` are you using?

Comment: h_name doesn't change throughout this process, even when getting the h_name reentered the same error shows. The types of the variables are the exact same as they were the first time also

Comment: @user14303139 What `port` is it failing at?

Comment: When the server is run on port 8001 (eg), the client will see the h_name is open but not on that port, so the code increments the port number to 8001 (from the original 8000 set at the start of the client code), this is the only argument that changes. Even if this function changes from a recursive one to only a while loop, the same problem occurs